# Is there a way to have a function running constantly?

Tags: javascript

I would like this function below to be running throughout the game, so when a player has no people left it will declare the winner. Is there a way to do this?

```
async function checkWinner() {
    if (document.getElementById('player1').innerText === '0') {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[1]} you have won the game</p>`;
        await sleep(3000);
        window.location.reload();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('player2').innerText === '0') {
        message.innerHTML = `<p>${players[0]} you have won the game</p>`;
        await sleep(3000);
        window.location.reload();
    }

}
```

Comment: Whatever function updates the number of "people" available to the player can simply call the `checkWinner()` function, which saves squandering resources.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the game and maybe share more code that would explain the usage of `checkWinner()`. From your tags it seems like you're creating a game without the use of any frameworks, am I right? If so, you somehow need to add `checkWinner()` to the function that manipulates the `players` variable. Using an interval for this would either be too slow for the game to function correctly or it would be a terrible waste of resources.

Comment: [Add the function as an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to a custom [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) such an event whenever you need it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SetInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function for that, e.g:

```js
setInterval(async () => {
  await checkWinner();
}, 1000)
```

This code will run the `checkWinner()` function every second.

Comment: He using an async function for which he needs to use await also

Comment: @MuhammadTariq no he doesn't. The first revision of this answer was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The way you run code repeatedly in JavaScript is by using a [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) timer.

```
setInterval(() => {
  // Your recurring code
}, 3000);
```

Note that this will run until you reload the page or stop the interval:

```
const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
  // Your recurring code
}, 3000);

clearInterval(myInterval); // this line will stop the interval when you call it.
```